# Where can I download the lastest version of the jQuery plugin, jstree (not GitHub)?

Tags: jstree

As stated in the title, I'm not familiar with GitHub and it's really complicated to find the right source packed for Windows. Any ideas of where I can find it? It appears that the version from jstree.com/demo is not going to work for our deadline.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub is where the author put the latest stable version.

It's his project, so his call:
http://github.com/downloads/vakata/jstree/jstree_pre1.0_fix_1.zip

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the same one that appears on jstree.com/demo, right?

Comment: so isn't it the same zip file that is at: http://code.google.com/p/jstree/ ? I just want to make sure that I'm not downloading a prior version to the latest.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer correct because perhaps I have formulated wrongly the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the latest version is: https://raw.github.com/vakata/jstree/v.1.0/dist/jstree.js and I'm looking for the latest because there are some bugs with the checkbox plugin using the stable version that you have suggested.. anyways, I guess someone can delete this answer or find it useful, so I'm leaving this here.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration control of jstree is poor and has to be ignored. I recommend going with the version from Ivan's site at www.jstree.com labeled "pre 1.0 fix 2". This links to:

```
    https://codeload.github.com/vakata/jstree/zip/v.pre1.0
```

which when unzipped expands into a directory jstree-v.pre1.0 all files are dated "Feb 27  2013"

The version mentioned above from from github

```
    http://cloud.github.com/downloads/vakata/jstree/jstree_pre1.0_fix_1.zip
```

expands into the current folder and most of the files are circa "Jun 25  2011"

jquery.jstree.js from both versions contains SVN status info:

```
/*
* jsTree 1.0-rc3
* http://jstree.com/
*
* Copyright (c) 2010 Ivan Bozhanov (vakata.com)
*
* Licensed same as jquery - under the terms of either the MIT License or the GPL Version 2 License
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
* $Date: 2011-02-09 01:17:14 +0200 (ÑÑ, 09 ÑÐµÐ²Ñ 2011) $
     * $Revision: 236 $
*/
```

However beyond compare reports 36 different sections for jquery.jstree.js.